# Which of the following is not equivalent to others?

Tags: c

Which of the following is not equivalent to the other two? Please tell me when it isn't output different from the other two.

```
 while (i<10) {...}

 for (;i<10:) {...}

 do {...} while (i<10);
```

I'll appreciate it for your answer.

Comment: put a `printf("%d\n", i);` into each block and you'll see.

Comment: What do *you* think? *Why* do you think that? And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Since the middle one (the `for (;i<10:) {...}` loop) doesn't compile and the others do, presumably that's the odd one?

Comment: I guess he meant
    `for (;i<10;) {...}`
And yes ... of course, is complete!

Comment: It's my first time to ask..forgive my unclear convey plz and thanks for your attention to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is different from the first two! If `i==15`, then the first two are not executed at all, while the `do {}` block gets executed once.

Comment: That's the point! I almost forget about the "for" and"while" may not execute the loop at all ,but the "do while" can execute even if the range of i isn't "<10".

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` loop is unlike the others in that it will execute at least one time because the condition check happens after the loop body. The other two structures first check whether `i<10`, then execute the loop body if true.

Comment: I know that,but I just can't get an example;the other answer inspire me that,when the "i" is not in the rage of "<10",the third one will excute while the other two don't.That's what I actually want to now.And thanks!